# Code for iOS 5.1 on Xcode 5?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I only have an iOS5.1 device to test my code on. Is it possible for me to run an app written in Xcode 5 on an iOS5.1 device? I'm a registered developer, I have a provisioning profile set up and everything. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can, set deployment target to 5.1.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for the most part. Just a bunch of errors that I have to go through haha/

Comment: Of course! Please do. EDIT: Just mention that you have to remove `arm64` from Architectures in "Build Settings."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, set deployment target to 5.1.

Edit: you have to remove `arm64` from Architectures in "Build Settings."